# How to config the generated code's placement in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Now I'm using IntelliJ, it's great. But there is one annoyance: It always place generated getter setter above the actual field, how can I change this behavior?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. When I generate getters/setters with Alt + Insert, it just generates Getters/Setters and place them at the caret position...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your mouse pointer below all the fields. ALT + INSERT -> Getter and Setter -> Select Fields -> OK. Should be it.

Comment: Wow, so easy. Turns out I always selected my fields from bottom to top and had my pointer above fields. Thank you ! :)